# Why does my asp.net webform page validation fail in IE9, but not Chrome(current version)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

This may seem like a simple question, but I have googled the crap out of it and can't find any clues.

Here is a basic page (trimmed down substantially for demo purposes)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NUBrand.master.cs" Inherits="nuservices_NUBrand" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua);
    if (isiPad == false) { // viewport tag breaks ipad portrait... don't use it if it's an ipad
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">');
    }
</script>
<%--<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="javascript/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!--<![endif]-->--%>

<%--js--%>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.stayInWebApp.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/global.js"></script>

<%--css--%><link href="resources/css/bootstrap-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="resources/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="all and (max-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/mobile.css" />

<script src="resources/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="mainHead">
    </header>
    <div id="pageHeader">
        <div id="breadcrumb">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHeaderLinks" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form id="Form1" runat="server" name="form1">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBodyWithForm" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphInputForm" runat="server" />
            </form>
            <div id="pageChildren">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="mainFooter">
    </footer>
</div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPageScripts" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

If the  content is not important, let me know and I can remove that too for the readers sake.

In the main part of the body I have three content placeholders

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBodyWithForm" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphInputForm" runat="server" />
```

I am using cphBody for most of my pages if that matters, the other ones are there for legacy reasons.

An example page that does not work in IE9 (but works fine in Chrome) looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="Server">
    <div class="row-fluid span12">
        <div class="span7">
            <%--validation summary--%>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" HeaderText="You must provide:"
                        ForeColor="#BF2E1A" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--career week date--%>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <span>Career Week Date:<%= UtilsWww.RequiredAsterisk %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="inDate">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="February" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="May" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="August" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="November" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Career Week date" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4"
                        ControlToValidate="inDate" Display="Dynamic" Text="X" EnableClientScript="True" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--Contact Email--%>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <span>Contact's email:<%= UtilsWww.RequiredAsterisk %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContactPersonEmail"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Contact Person's Email"
                        ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtContactPersonEmail"
                        ToolTip="A contact person email must be provided!">X</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Valid Email Address"
                        ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtContactPersonEmail"
                        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ToolTip="Email addresses must conform to internet email standards!">X</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" CssClass="formSubmitButton" OnClick="Linkbutton1_Click">
                        Submit<img src="resources/images/icn_getstarted.png" alt="submit" class="btn-arrow"/>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The codebehind for this example page does this:

```
protected void Linkbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();

    if (!this.IsValid) return;
    ...Do some other Stuff...
}
```

This is the line that is where all my problems are happening:

```
if (!this.IsValid) return;
```

In Chrome, that statement does not return, everything is valid, it does it's thing.

In IE9, that line hits the return statement and I am left sad and confused.

So what do you think is happening here? Where can I look (I have tried fiddler, following in the IE dev tools to debug the js, it gets confusing, I have compared they code in the 'broken pages' to the few that do actually work in IE9, no real difference)? I would love to get an answer like "Oh add this and everything will be great!", but I don't see that happening. So I am asking where to look for solutions to this, I am completely lost.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the dev console to see if there are any javascript errors thrown?

Comment: Are you doing anything to the form fields in `Page Load` (e.g. resetting/defaults)?

Comment: @emd their are two js error coming in from some unrelated libraries. Do you think that could play a part in it?

Comment: @EdSF nothing is happening on Page_Load, its blank.

Comment: The script errors could affect client-side validation on IE. Check what data is actually POSTed on Postback (and/or turn-off client-side validation for your controls just to debug).

Comment: @davidisawesome Can you post the JS errors you got? And the libraries they come from?

Comment: @Marcel, I just cleaned up the js error (loading the libraries in the right order, the errors were just '$ is not defined' coming from the stay-in-web-app script. I got rid of the errors and am going to test to see if that fixed it now.

Comment: It worked! So I guess the unrelated js errors we're blocking everything else.. Thanks! Someone want to post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

To give credit where credit is due, see the comments on the question. We arrived at the answer from there, so I will post it here.

There were a couple of javascript errors being thrown on the page (in unrelated libraries that we're being pulled in). Chrome obviously did not have an issue with this, but IE did. I correct the js error and the pages worked fine again. woot!